# Laptop Overheating - Lenovo Z500

Tags: laptop, lenovo, overheating

Hi I have a Lenovo Z500 with i7, 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD. In Windows 7,8 and 8.1 I don't have any problem with the laptop temperature while running just the system or surfing the web, but under ubuntu 13.10 the system is overheating a lot !!! I dont now what the problem is and how to fix it.

I tried using TLP and Laptop-mode-tools and the system is still overheating. I wonder if the OS can damage the components by overheating? Is there any solution (software) to keep Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop without overheating? 
The ouput of scaling_governor is : ondemand. Temperatures : Acpitz 54, Nvidia GPU - 66, Intel CPU - 75 , Core Zero 74, Core 1- 70, Core 2 - 72, Core 3 - 74, this values are from Psensor Monitor. I tried upgrading to 14.04 but I cant make made ubuntu work in paralel with windows 8.1 were I dont have any problem with temperature . Why only in ubuntu 13.10 and how to fix it ?

Comment: I've never heard of this problem with an i7 CPU although it was addressed on the AMD platform. Is the cooling fan vent blocked/dusty?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your graphics card, the temperatures you reach (are you really overheating?) and the output of `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`.

Comment: Are you using Nvidia graphics or the Intel? Have you installed the Nvidia drivers? Recommend you upgrade to the latest BIOS version for your laptop and upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: The ouput of scaling_governor is : ondemand. Temperatures : Acpitz 54, Nvidia GPU - 66, Intel CPU - 75 , Core Zero 74, Core 1- 70, Core 2 - 72, Core 3 - 74, this values are from Psensor Monitor. I tried upgrading to 14.04 but I cant make made ubuntu work in paralel with 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Lenovo Z500 CORE i7 running on Ubuntu 14.04 and had experienced overheating too. This is due to the dedicated graphics card, a nVidia GT 635m, running constantly, instead of using the integrated Intel 4000 HD graphics chip.

You should set up your Ubuntu to use the internal graphics to decrease heat and when wanting to use the dedicated graphics, the nVidia, use it with Bumblebee, e.g. `$ primusrun [your-app]`. Follow the online instructions either here:
[Bumblebee Installation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation)

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia virtualgl linux-headers-generic`
4. Reboot

or here:
[How to install nVidia drivers with Bumblebee on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04)

If you want to run Ubuntu 14.04 in parallel with Win 8.1 you need to install it on a separate partition to Windows 8.1, using one that's available or shrinking a used one **with caution**. Follow these guidelines: [WindowsDualBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)