# How to install nVidia drivers with Bumblebee on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, nvidia-prime

As the title, how can I correctly setup nvidia-optimus technology on Ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/is-a-nvidia-geforce-with-optimus-technology-supported-by-ubuntu)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**NB: this post is the result of many days spent reading various stuffs on the web, so take it at your own risk. It was tested on Ubuntu 12.04/12.10/13.04/13.10/14.04 (all 64bit) with nVidia GT650M graphic card. Feel free to add comments and suggestions**

---

### Install nVidia and bumblebee

1.
First of all, we have to delete all the video drivers on the computer:

```bsh
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

Then bumblebee in case if you have installed it previously:

```bsh
sudo apt-get remove --purge bumblebee*
```

We have also to delete all the nouveau driver with:

```bsh
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

To be sure to have deleted the whole stuffs, try to type `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` and `dpkg -l | grep bumblebee`: it shouldn't return anything. For `dpkg -l | grep nouveau` it is likely that it returns some lines saying `libdrm-nouveauXXXXX`; for now, just ignore them.

2.
Then, we have to assure to have all the headers typing:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install linux-source && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

3.
The next thing to do is to blacklist the remaining nouveau drivers and some other packages that could cause problems:

```bsh
sudo cp /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.bak
 sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Adding the following lines at the end of file:

```bsh
# Necessary to install nvidia drivers
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
blacklist nvidia-173
blacklist nvidia-96
blacklist nvidia-current
blacklist nvidia-173-updates
blacklist nvidia-96-updates
alias nvidia nvidia_current_updates
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
options nouveau modeset=0
```

Just save and exit.

4.
Now, run the best knows ubuntu commands

```bsh
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

5.
From now, we works on tty. Open the tty1 console with CTRL+ALT+F1 and login with your username and password. Then execute:

```bsh
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Now we will install the drivers. Execute:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install nvidia-XXX-updates nvidia-settings
```

where XXX is the latest stable drivers. I'm using the 331 drivers, but I've read somewhere that the 343 are available to download (don't know if they are stable).

**N.B:** With the latest driver versions, it also install `nvidia-prime` by default. This technology is intended to automatically switch between Intel and nVidia graphic card without user intervention. To do this, it leaves both the cards turned on. Optimus, on the other hand, turn on the nVidia graphic card only with explicit user request; it translates in significantly less power consumption respect to prime.

I personally prefer optimus over prime, but if you don't bother on the enormous waste of energy, stop here. Otherwise, you have two options:

- completely delete prime (`sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-prime`);
- leave prime there; in section "Prime with optimus" we will see how to make optirun
  work also with prime installed

6.
Now, we have to install bumblebee and the virtualgl packages with

```bsh
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia virtualgl virtualgl-libs virtualgl-libs-ia32:i386 virtualgl-libs:i386
```

Then, we have to add our user in the bumblebee group with:

```bsh
sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee $USER
```

And then reboot the pc.

7.
Login on your user account, open a new terminal window and type:

```bsh
cd /etc/bumblebee
ls -Al
```

Among the various listed files, there should be two in particular: `bumblebee.conf` and `xorg.nvidia.conf`. Let's make a backup copy of both with:

```bsh
sudo cp FILE_NAME FILE_NAME.bak
```

You should replace FILE_NAME with the actual name of the file. Then, let's go to modify the first file with `sudo gedit bumblebee.conf`, adding (all without quotes)

- [bumblebeed] section: after "Driver=" insert "nvidia"
- [nvidia-driver] section: after "KernelDriver=" insert "nvidia-XXX-updates"
- [nvidia-driver] section: after "LibraryPath=" insert "/usr/lib/nvidia-XXX-updates, /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-XXX-updates"
- [nvidia-driver] section: after "XorgModulePath=" insert "/usr/lib/nvidia-XXX-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"

Assure that the "XorgConfFile" under [nvidia-driver] is equal to "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia" (again, without quotes), then save and close gedit.

Now we have to edit the other file with `sudo gedit xorg.conf.nvidia` (in this case we have to insert the quotes also!!). Replace
`Option "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP"` with   `Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"`, save and exit.

8.
Run `gedit /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf` and make sure that all the lines containing `blacklist <something>` are not commented (i.e. they don't start with `#`).

9.
At this point, run the following command

```bsh
sudo service bumblebeed start
```

If it returns an error, try to run again the command with restart rather than start. If you have still errors, something like:

```bsh
restart: Unknown job: bumblebeed
```

It's probably something wrong in the bumblebee.conf file; so, recheck step 7.

If instead the result is similar to:

```bsh
bumblebeed start/running, process XXXXX
```

You're soon done setting up bumblebee!

10.
Now we can simply run `optirun glxspheres` or `optirun glxspheres64`. If all work as expected, you have an output like this:

```bsh
$ optirun glxspheres64
Polygons in scene: 62464
Visual ID of window: 0x20
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 650M/PCIe/SSE2
182.253407 frames/sec - 203.394802 Mpixels/sec
182.940725 frames/sec - 204.161849 Mpixels/sec
....
```

To double-check that we are actually using nvidia-drivers, open another terminal while `optirun <application>` is running, then type `sudo lshw -c display | grep driver`. The result should be something like that.

```bsh
configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

If, on the other hand, you close all the application started with `optirun` it should show only the intel driver. That's it!!

---

### Install Bumblebee UI

Thanks to this answer from Pavak Paul, here is the instructions to add the bumblebee user interface on Ubuntu 14.04 to manage apps to be opened using nVidia.

1.
Install Python App Indicator:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install python-appindicator
```

2.
Install Git:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install git
```

3.
Make a directory for git:

```bsh
mkdir git && cd git
```

4.
Check out the repository:

```bsh
git clone https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bumblebee-ui.git
cd bumblebee-ui
sudo ./INSTALL
```

5.
Go to Startup Applications and add bumblebee-indicator [click on Add, then insert the Name and comment that you want; insert `bumblebee-indicator` in the command box and click on Add).

6.
Reboot.

---

### Prime with optimus

If you want to have the option to also use `nvidia-prime` sometimes, try to follow the instructions below.

1.
To prevent `bumblebeed` from starting at boot-time, execute:

```bsh
echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/bumblebeed.override
```

2.
This point is the most problematic; it prevents bumblebee to blacklist nVidia drivers and should result in graphic session freeze. Try it at your own risk!
Run:

```bsh
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf
```

And comment the line containing your nVidia XXX drivers. It should result in something like that.

```bsh
# XXX
#blacklist nvidia-XXX
#blacklist nvidia-XXX-updates
blacklist nvidia-experimental-XXX
```

3.
Reboot the system and launch `nvidia-settings`. The final situation is this:

If you select "Intel (Power save)" in nvidia-settings, you have only the Intel graphic card turned on by default. You still have to run an application with `optirun` to use the nVidia graphic card

```bsh
sudo service bumblebeed start
optirun <application>
```

If instead you want to use the "Nvidia (Performance)" profile, select it from nvidia-settings, then login/logout and all should work automatically. The only thing is that you don't have to launch `bumblebeed` daemon with this profile selected because it could cause troubles.

#### In case you have problems:

1.
If you want to use only `nvidia-prime`:

```bsh
sudo apt-get --purge remove bumblebee*
```

Then reboot.

2.
If you want to use only optimus without removing nvidia-prime, edit again the previous file:

```bsh
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf
```

Uncommenting (removing the # character) from the lines previously modified:

```bsh
# XXX
blacklist nvidia-XXX
blacklist nvidia-XXX-updates
blacklist nvidia-experimental-XXX
```

And rebooting. In this case, you can leave bumblebeed run at boot-time:

```bsh
sudo rm /etc/init/bumbebeed.override
```

Comment: I followed the instructions on Ubuntu 14.04 , but my screen goes black after splash screen, and I am unable to login. Using Dell xps l502x,  nvidia gfrc gt540m.

Comment: Are you sure that you have followed all the instructions from the beginning? Anyway, press CTRL+ALT+F1 to access the tty, then enter your login credentials and restart from the beginning.

Comment: Yes , found the problem , i had to blacklist nvidia-346 `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf` and added these lines `#346
blacklist nvidia-346
blacklist nvidia-346-updates
blacklist nvidia-experimental-346` at the end of file. Working fine. Thanks for response, upvoting your answer, btw do you know why i am getting 60fps on both cards. Is there any way to override it?

Comment: glad to help :) Are you sure of that? What is the result of `glxspheres64` and `optirun glxspheres64`? Run the previous commands for a few seconds and read the output.

Comment: Ok i solved the problem by using `vblank_mode=0 primusrun ./glxgears` or we can use `vblank_mode=0 optirun -b primus ./glxgears`. thanks :)

Comment: great tutorial, but are the virtualgl packages needed? And I didn't have glxspheres64 installed, but running other applications with optirun gives the result at the end of the section... I assume this is good?

Comment: please note, i had to install xorg-edgers ppa to get the virtualgl packages. There were not available in a clean install Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I tried this but Additional Drivers still says it's using nouvea.  Nvidia doesn't appear in the output of lshw either...

Comment: @jeffythedragonslayer are you sure to have followed the whole procedure? What parameters did you use with `lshw`? `sudo lshw -c display` should returns all the graphic cards, including your nvidia card.

Comment: Yeah, sudo lshw -c display didn't show it.  However I manually selected 346 from additional drivers and changed xxx from 331 to 346 in bumblebee.conf (and got rid of -updates on the end, that package didn't exist)  Optirun ran great, until I rebooted, then black screen of death.

Comment: @jeffythedragonslayer this is strange, what is the output of `sudo lshw -c display | grep vendor`

Comment: vendor: NVIDIA Corporation and vendor: Intel Corportation

Comment: @jeffythedragonslayer ok so it is detected in some ways. No need to go on additional drivers btw: the simplest thing to do if you have a black screen is to purge the nvidia drivers. When you have this black screen,  open tty1 with CTRL+ALT+F1 and start the procedure described in the answer from the first point on.

Comment: First thanks for the nice post. However it only worked partially for me. If I stop before point 6., (that is before installing bumblebee) I get to the login screen but can't login anymore. The combination of Prime and Bumblebee didn't work for me neither. And then I have two problems, my nvidia-settings is empty like here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/451405/empty-nvidia-settings-after-install-v-331-67-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04   and then I also can't connect any external monitor. xrandr shows almost nothing as output.

Comment: It worked for me! I also had to add `alias nvidia-uvm nvidia_352_uvm` to `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf`. Source: http://askubuntu.com/a/525883/53752

Comment: This is by far the most up to date tutorial I'm up-voting this. I checked, and it works for 17.10. Good job.