# Run OpenGL apps with CUDA with Nvidia Optimus and Bumblebee

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.10, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I am attempting to start learning CUDA using my old laptop with a hybrid Nvidia GT650M/Intel iGPU setup. I have tried following the instructions on a couple resources[1,2,3]. Those resources helped tremendously and gave me a working `nvcc`. However, while most of the samples compiled, none of the samples that use OpenGL work at all. I assume this is because my installed OpenGL drivers are for my Intel GPU, but I was forced to not install the OpenGL drivers during the Nvidia driver installation to avoid overwriting the old drivers (for my intel card) that I need.

Is it possible to install the nvidia opengl drivers alongside the ones I have installed already? There seems to be a flag in the NVIDIA*.run script that allows me to change the installation directory for opengl files, but I don't know if this will mess things up or not work at all.

[1] [How can I get nVidia CUDA or OpenCL working on a laptop with nVidia discrete card/Intel Integrated Graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131506/how-can-i-get-nvidia-cuda-or-opencl-working-on-a-laptop-with-nvidia-discrete-car)

[2] [How to install nVidia drivers with Bumblebee on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[3] [(Guide) Installing Nvidia + Bumblebee + CUDA for Optimus enabled Laptops](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?21956-(Guide)-Installing-Nvidia-Bumblebee-CUDA-for-Optimus-enabled-Laptops)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install CUDA 7.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 using runfile installation, because this worked for me starting from CUDA 5.0. I have a laptop with Optimus technology (Nvidia GT520M discrete card + Intel embedded card), thus I had to pass "--no-opengl-libs" flag to installer script. I was following Nvidia guide from here: [CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7.5/Prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf).  Unfortunately this method turned out to be unreliable if I wanted to run OpenGL samples and work with graphics (samples which don't use OpenGL work properly). It gives me an error "cudaErrorDevicesUnavailable". **Carefully** reading installation guide tells you that CUDA 7.5 works with ubuntu 14.04 and kernel version 3.13! Ok, no problem, I've formatted partition once again and run script... but It didn't work either. And again **carefully** reading installation guide tells you that using package manager installation type is recommended where possible! So removed runfile installed cuda driver and toolkit and used .deb packages. BAM! and it works like a charm! :)

In conclusion, the easies and probably the safest way of installing CUDA 7.5 on Optimus laptop is:

1. Install ubuntu 14.04 with 3.13 (trusty) kernel version
2. Follow Package Manager installation part from Nvidia guide: [CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7.5/Prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf)

[EDIT]

Unfortunately it seems that debugging won't work this way...