# Can't install virtualgl and optirun doesn't work

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, 15.04, virtualgl

I've looked into this in various already created topics but none seems to help. Everything goes around on installing virtualgl THAT I seem not be able to do because I can't find it anywhere ( more info later in the question ) or installing proprietary software from NVidia that I've already as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04). 
What I've done so far:

1. Reinstal NVidia driver and bumblebee WITHOUT any virtualgl thing using the Answer shown before.

Now, whatever I try to run something using optirun it fails because it can't load GPU driver ( more info later )

Well... Since I cant yet comment in the post I mentioned before I decided to create this question. If in any luck @tigerjack89 sees this, know that everything went well in what you suggested except the installing part of virtualgl and the optirun final part because something.

---

**Now with the output part.**

Trying to install virtualgl and comrades fails. I've already added Bumblebee ppa and aparently that should solve the problem BUT it doesn't.

Trying to install virtualgl and others.

```
apt-get install virtualgl virtualgl-libs virtualgl-libs-ia32:i386 virtualgl-libs:i386
```

I get an error that says something like: `package virtualgl isn't available but is referenced by another package` ( I can't copy and past it directly because my system language isn't english and you woudn't understand it )

Using the `apt-cache search virtualgl` I get this as result:

`bumblebee - NVIDIA Optimus support for Linux`
`primus - client-side GPU offloading for NVIDIA Optimus`

And this is my first problem.

About the error I get when trying to run `optirun APP`, I've read that it can be solved by installing virtualgl and the others packages i've already metioned. Anyway, as the problem might be something else, here is what I get when I try to run, for example, `optirun glxspheres64`

`[ 5386.790679] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver`

UPDATE 1: apparently when I and do `nvidia-detector` is returns none ... So am I to suppose that the nvidia driver was not installed ?

Comment: Bumblebee doesn't work, nvidia-prime doesn't work, Optimus notebooks in general don't work in any Linux. I tryed everything possible and it just won't work no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

You can download latest version [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualgl/files/).

I also had difficulties with `optirun`+`primus`, that `optirun -vv` outputted a `segmentation fault` with any process that actually used 3D acceleration, which made it useless. But `optirun -b virtualgl` solved it.