# Bumblebee installation problems for Nvidia GTX 970M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a weirds problems with ubuntu 15 when I try install bumblebee on my MSI GS60-2QE.

I had try many installations way especialy this one: [How to install nVidia drivers with Bumblebee on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04?newreg=47c9460cf2234bb9a60da77e5b27d7ea)

I only change the driver version: "nvidia-346-updates".
But the problem persists. He look like this :

```
     optirun -vv glxspheres
[ 2189.097699] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 2189.098258] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[ 2189.098562] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[ 2189.098579] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[ 2189.098586] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 2189.098592] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[ 2189.098598] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
[ 2189.098604] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[ 2189.098610] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[ 2189.098616] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[ 2189.098622] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[ 2189.098628] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
[ 2189.098727] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge primus
[ 2189.102704] [INFO]Response: No - error: Could not load GPU driver

[ 2189.102732] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[ 2189.102740] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[ 2189.102770] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[ 2189.102777] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

In the "/var/log/syslog" I found that :

```
May 22 01:08:12 fondation bumblebeed[763]: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:816 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='off'
May 22 01:08:12 fondation bumblebeed[763]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'off': Function not implemented
May 22 01:08:12 fondation bumblebeed[763]: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:816 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='off'
May 22 01:08:12 fondation bumblebeed[763]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'off': Function not implemented
May 22 01:08:12 fondation bumblebeed[763]: [ 2189.102601] [ERROR]Module nouveau could not be loaded (timeout?)
May 22 01:08:12 fondation bumblebeed[763]: [ 2189.102629] [ERROR]Could not load GPU driver
```

I also generate a bumblebee bug-report, can be found here : [Bug Report](https://transfer.sh/1gITOY/bumblebee-bugreport-20150522-010350.tar.gz)

If anyone has had the same problem and managed to solve it. I'd love he shares how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems you have to replace all hyphens with underscores in KernelDriver=nvidia-346-updates in /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf. So it should be KernelDriver=nvidia_346_updates

Comment: Thanks for your answer I changed my /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf but the problem is still here. What is the driver version you have install ? I try with 346-updates, maybe it's the problem.