# I want to install Nvidia module 352.30 on ubuntu 14.04 (2 video cards intel and nvidia)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lightdm

[This is my hardware](http://www.toshiba.com.ro/contents/ro_RO/PRODUCT_DESC/files/1161625.pdf)

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface

```
WARNING: You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported by the 352.30 NVIDIA Linux graphics driver installed in this system.  
ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before installing.  For further details, please see the section INSTALLING THE NVIDIA DRIVER in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  
You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

*How can I use the 352.30 module anyway?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install nVidia drivers with Bumblebee on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: This is what you need, the latest drivers are not supported on this GPU, you have a hybrid GPU bumblebee can utilize this

Answer (score 1):

A much better way to install 352 driver is running in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

Comment: +1, but is there a reason for `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`?

Comment: @A.B. Anyway it is not safe to keep the ppa connected. Who knows what they may upload there ;-) Previously there used to be lots of problems. And this will avoid the question: after update Ubuntu does not boot )))

Comment: Ah ok, I agree =)

Comment: Okay, but is there **even a reason** for `add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`? That PPA [doesn't contain any packages](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=nvidia&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=) whose name contain `nvidia`.

Comment: They've been removed recently. I will change the answer. Things change in this world. @theV0ID