# Nvidia-prime switch logout-login doesn't work (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: 15.10, nvidia-prime

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 and switched from Bumblebee to Nvidia Prime. I'm currently using the 355.11 driver from https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa, but the problem also occurs when using the drivers in the official Ubuntu repo.

Prime works as expected, apart from the fact that I need to reboot in order for it to switch cards. If I logout and try to login again after switching, it just keeps showing me the login screen after I type in my password. This happens regardless of whether I switch from Nvidia to Intel or from Intel to NVidia.

Here's my /var/log/Xorg.0.log after I switch from Nvidia to Intel and try to login: http://termbin.com/n75a

When I go to TTY1 and do "prime-select nvidia" (the driver that was loaded during boot), I can login again at TTY7.

This question seems similar to [ubuntu 14.04 - nvidia prime only works on restart (logout-login doesnt work)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596357/ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-prime-only-works-on-restart-logout-login-doesnt-work), but the only answer there is to install Bumblebee...

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why did you switch from bumblebee to PRIME???!!!! Is there a serious reason? For me PRIME gives me nothing but problems, screen tearing all over the place and no Vsync in games!!!

I strongly recommend you switch to bumblebee with the nvidia-355, works like a charm for me and many others!!

Comment: Because when my Bumblebee configuration crashed after upgrading from nvidia-346 to 352 and I went looking for a solution, I got the idea that Bumblebee was or would be discontinued. In fact, someone on IRC literatlly told me this. I also read a lot of conflicting messages regarding performance in Bumblebee vs Prime.  

Not that I didn't try. I can't even remember how often I've uninstalled and reinstalled nouveua, nvidia-340, -352, or -355 with Prime or Bumblebee. Nothing worked, until I got to 355 + Prime. I'm hesitant to try Bumblebee again because I finally have a working solution...

Comment: Well you may try to follow the instructions in the answer, there is a very high chance you didn't do all of these?! Just change nvidia-352 to 355! http://askubuntu.com/questions/689724/bumblebee-on-asus-zenbook-ux303lb/689802#689802

Comment: Also bumblebee is not discontinued at all!! It is the REAL optimus support for linux and still gets bugfixes and maintenance! https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues

Comment: Or maybe -just maybe- the same Linux drivers/software don't work equally well on every hardware configuration. Imagine that. I did in fact follow the instructions in that answer for Bumblebee + nvidia-340 and nvidia-352, those being the only drivers in the official repos. Did not work. The only time I ever got Bumblebee to work was with the ppa-edgers nvidia-346 drivers, before I upgraded to 15.10. I'm happy to hear Bumblebee works great for you, but I'll wait for a bit for some input from other people before I try messing around with it again.

Comment: OK, fine, i was just trying to be helpful. Good Luck!

Comment: My mistake, in that case. I got the feeling that you were getting worked up about it, as if you were saying "Bumblebee is awesome and works flawlessly, so the only explanation is that you are doing something wrong". Thanks for trying! (They way things are going now, I'll probably get tired of rebooting each time I want to play a game soon and give BB another go anyway. :P)

Comment: Alright,  since there were no other responses, I went ahead and installed Bumblebee again. This time, it works perfectly, pressumably because I'm now using the packages from the graphics-drivers PPA. Thanks!