# No detection of external monitors, xrandr shows few things, hybrid graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I have a hybrid graphics setting with an Intel Graphics 4th Gen and an Nvidia GTX 960M.

I would like to use sometimes the nvidia card and at the same time have output to an external VGA or HDMI monitor.

I have tried to follow several guides:
[How to set up nVidia Optimus/Bumblebee in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04?rq=1)

[How to install nVidia drivers with Bumblebee on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver)

I have managed to install succesfully the nvidia drivers together with bumblebee, and not so succesfully using nvidia-prime (I cannot really switch to using only nvidia). But the biggest problem is that with or without nvidia, with or without bumblebee, even using the xorg nouveau packages, I do not get any output to external monitors.

This is what I get from xrandr:

`~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      0.00*`

I have tried many possible solutions on the web, but still find this very confusing.

Thanks!